# How to get different data from same class in selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I have searched in stackoverflow but haven't found any answer.

I have written a script in python to get data from this website.

> https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Reduplication_of_adjectives

The page have two-three sentence structure and 4-5 example.
For ex:-

> Structure 1
>       
> - Example 1
>       
> - Example 2
>
> Structure 2
>       
> - Example 1
>       
> - Example 2
>
> Structure 3
>       
> - Example 1
>       
> - Example 2
>       
> - Example 3

I managed to get all sentence structure and example sentence but how can I get example sentence for structure 1 , structure 2 , structure 3 separately.
Also how not to get wrong sentences.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\<user>\Documents\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe") # change it

save_file = open("export.txt", "w", encoding="utf8")
wrong_link_file = open("link_with_wrong.txt", "w", encoding="utf8")

url = "https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Reduplication_of_adjectives"

time.sleep(1)

driver.get(url)

time.sleep(3)

#jiegou = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/section/div[3]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/h1")

jiegou = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("jiegou")

usedfor = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ibox']/ul/li[6]/div[2]")

heading = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='innerbodycontent']/div/div[2]/h1")

sen = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("spaced")

wrong = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("x")


# if page contain wrong sentence 
found = False
if len(wrong) > 0:
        found = True
        print("..............Found..............." + url)


for j in jiegou:
        jiegou_str = ":: " + j.text + " ::"
        print(jiegou_str)
        save_file.write(jiegou_str)
        print("\n.........................................................\n")

        save_file.write("\n\n")

st_sen=""
for s in sen:
        st_sen = str(s.text)
        if len(wrong) > 0 and wrong[0].text in st_sen:
                continue

        if "。" in st_sen :
                sep = "。"
                st_sen = st_sen.split(sep,1)[0].strip()
                st_sen += " " + sep
        if "？" in st_sen:
                sep = "？"
                st_sen = st_sen.split(sep,1)[0].strip()
                st_sen  += " " + sep

        all_set = st_sen +"\t"+ jiegou_str +"\t"+ usedfor.text +"\t"+ heading.text + "\t" + url

        print(all_set)
        save_file.write(all_set)
print("\n\n")
save_file.write("\n\n")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Get the structure and example in a sequence.
Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `visibility_of_all_elements_located`() and following `xpath` option.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Reduplication_of_adjectives"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\<user>\Documents\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)
structureelements=WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//h3[./span[text()='Structure']]/following::div[1]")))

for structure in structureelements:
    print("============================")
    print(structure.text)
    print("========================================")

    for example in structure.find_elements_by_xpath(".//following::h3[1]/following::div[1]//li[@class='spaced']"):
        print(example.text)
```

**Output**:

```
============================
Adj. + Adj. + 的 (+ Noun)
========================================
你 的 脸 红 红 的 。
Nǐ de liǎn hóng hóng de.
Your face is red.
宝宝 的 眼睛 大 大 的 。
Bǎobao de yǎnjīng dà dà de.
The baby's eyes are big.
今晚 的 月亮 圆 圆 的 。
Jīnwǎn de yuèliàng yuán yuán de.
The moon is round tonight.
她 爸爸 高 高 胖 胖 的 。
Tā bàba gāo gāo pàng pàng de.
Her father is tall and fat.
我 妹妹 瘦 瘦 小 小 的 。
Wǒ mèimei shòu shòu xiǎo xiǎo de.
My little sister is thin and small.
============================
A A B B + 的 (+ Noun)
========================================
高兴 → 高高兴兴
gāoxìng ￫ gāogāo-xìngxìng
happy
热闹 → 热热闹闹
rènao ￫ rèrè-nāonāo
noisy, boisterous
漂亮 → 漂漂亮亮
piàoliang ￫ piàopiào-liāngliāng
pretty
舒服 → 舒舒服服
shūfu ￫ shūshū-fūfū
comfortable
安静 → 安安静静
ānjìng ￫ ānān-jìngjìng
quiet and still
============================
AABB + 地 + Verb
========================================
我们 清清楚楚 地 看到 他 跟 一 个 胖 胖 的 男人 上 车 了 。
Wǒmen qīngqīng-chǔchǔ de kàndào tā gēn yīgè pàng pàng de nánrén shàngchē le.
We clearly saw him get in the car with a fat man.
我 真 想 舒舒服服 地 躺 在 沙发 上 看 电视 。
Wǒ zhēn xiǎng shūshū-fūfū de tǎng zài shāfā shàng kàn diànshì.
I'd really like to comfortably lie on the couch and watch TV.
你 妈妈 辛辛苦苦 地 做 了 两 个 小时 的 饭，你 怎么 不 吃 ？
Nǐ māma xīnxīn-kǔkǔ de zuò le liǎng gè xiǎoshí de fàn, nǐ zěnme bù chī?
Your mother labored over this meal for two hours, and you aren't going to eat it?
============================
Subj. + ABAB
========================================
妹妹 快 过 生日 了 ，我 打算 给 她 办 一 个 生日 派对 ，热闹 热闹 。
Mèimei kuài guò shēngrì le, wǒ dǎsuàn gěi tā bàn yī gè shēngrì pàiduì, rènao rènao.
My little sister's birthday is coming and I plan to throw her a birthday party and have a blast.
来 ，喝 点 酒 ，高兴 高兴 。
Lái, hē diǎn jiǔ, gāoxìng gāoxìng.
Come on, have a little wine and enjoy yourself.
到 这里 来 凉快 凉快 。
Dào zhèlǐ lái liángkuai liángkuai.
Come over here and cool off.
我 想 去 外面 走走 ，安静 一下 。
Wǒ xiǎng qù wàimiàn zǒuzou, ānjìng yīxià.
I'd like to take a walk outside, get some quiet time.
想 不 想 去 做 个 按摩 ，放松 一下 。
Xiǎng bu xiǎng qù zuò gè ànmó, fàngsōng yīxià.
Would you like to go get a massage and unwind?
```

Comment: Aren't 2 divs missing with `//h3[./span[text()='Structure']]/following::div[1]`? 4 structures instead of 6, since first and last grammar points have 2 structures. Maybe a one liner  XPath would be enough for this problem : `//div[@class='jiegou']/p[1]|//li[@class="spaced"]`.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it. If two structures present then one structure get missed. What will be the possible solutions to this?